# A module cannot have multiple default exports.ts(2528)

Tags: redux

I'm trying to implement switch case for my products in Redux. I'm importing the cases from a file named productConstants using multiple export defaults. Problem is, the moment I write multiple lines, my screen turns red with this error 'A module cannot have multiple default exports.ts(2528)'

productReducers.js file

````
    ALL_PRODUCTS_REQUEST, 
    ALL_PRODUCTS_SUCCESS, 
    ALL_PRODUCTS_FAIL} from '../constants/productConstants'

export const productsReducer = (state ={ products: [] }, action => {
    switch(action.type) {


        default:
            return state;
    }
})

my productConstants.js file
```export default ALL_PRODUCTS_REQUEST = 'ALL_PRODUCT_REQUEST'

export default ALL_PRODUCTS_SUCCESS = 'ALL_PRODUCT_SUCCESS'

export default ALL_PRODUCTS_FAIL = 'ALL_PRODUCT_FAIL'

export default CLEAR_ERRORS = 'CLEAR_ERRORS'

here is my store.js file
```//import { configureStore } from '@reduxjs/toolkit'
import {  createStore, combineReducers, applyMiddleware } from 'redux';
import thunk from 'redux-thunk';
import { composeWithDevTools } from 'redux-devtools-extension'

const reducer = combineReducers({

})

let initialState = {}

const middleware = [thunk];
const store = createStore( reducer, initialState, composeWithDevTools(applyMiddleware(...middleware))) 

export default store;

and finally, my index.js file
```import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import App from "./App";

import { Provider } from 'react-redux'

import store from './store'

ReactDOM.render(
  <Provider store={store}>
    <App />
  </Provider>,
  document.getElementById('root')
);

How do I do away with this error? A module cannot have multiple default exports.ts(2528)
productConstants.js(1, 1): The first export default is here.
````

Comment: Maybe this helps:
https://bobbyhadz.com/blog/typescript-a-module-cannot-have-multiple-default-exports

Comment: This helped me alot @Svein Terje Gaup

Answer (score 1):

A module can have only one default export per module, meaning that in one JS file only one variable (or function) can be exported with the `default` keyword.

You can convert them all to named export:

```
export const ALL_PRODUCTS_FAIL = 'ALL_PRODUCT_FAIL'
```

Comment: I've replaced default keyword with const and it's working perfectly fine.